# JavaFX loading fonts using CSS

Tags: css, javafx, fonts

I know this is old, but it is just not working with me, already checked :

[JavaFX custom Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336542/javafx-custom-fonts/33342752#33342752)

and

[How to embed .ttf fonts is JavaFx 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855677/how-to-embed-ttf-fonts-is-javafx-2-2)

digital-clock.css :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'DINRegular';
src: url('../fonts/DINRegular.tff'); // also tried url('/fonts/DINRegular.tff'); and url('fonts/DINRegular.tff'); 
}

.label {
    -fx-font-family: 'DINRegular';
    -fx-font-size: 30;
}

.button .text {
    -fx-font-family: 'DINRegular';
}
```

loading the css with :

```
getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style/digital-clock.css").toExternalForm());
```

[image: resources]

loading font programatically doesnt work either :

example :

```
public static javafx.scene.text.Font loadFont(String name) {
    return javafx.scene.text.Font.loadFont(FXMLConstants.class.getResource("/fonts/"+"digital"+".ttf").toExternalForm(), 12);
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the tree of your compile target directory look like?  Or the contents of the jar file `jar tvf <myjarfile.jar>`?

Comment: Note, there was a report that the [font-family attribute of @font-face is ignored in Java 8u60](http://www.guigarage.com/2014/10/integrate-custom-fonts-javafx-application-using-css/).  Maybe open your font in some kind of true type viewer application and verify that the name embedded in the font is reapply `DINRegular`, as whatever name you use must match whatever is in the font file.

Comment: Note that if you package your application as a jar, the `..` specifier will not work when you load the CSS using getResource, as the `jar:` protocol used by the [JavaFX CSS `<url>` type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeurl) does not process `..` parent directory specifiers.  Still, the absolute path `/fonts/DINRegular.ttf` should have resolved correctly if the file is in the target directory or jar file.

Comment: @jewelsea thank you,, kindly check the edited answer ? its kinda weird