# Cannot use custom font in javaFX using CSS Styling

Tags: css, javafx

I'm trying to add a Global font to my javaFX application using CSS.
I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336542/javafx-custom-fonts/33342752#33342752), however I can't seem to load the font, and the error message is not helpful.

```
jan 12, 2022 12:24:25 PM javafx.css.CssParser reportException
WARNING: Please report java.lang.NullPointerException at:
```

The error messages finishes here, not showing where the problem is.

My code directory:
[pacman directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxYez.png)

My main.java:

```
package finalPacman;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("pacman.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        primaryStage.setTitle("PacMan");
        Controller controller = loader.getController();
        root.setOnKeyPressed(controller);
        double sceneWidth = controller.getBoardWidth() + 20.0;
        double sceneHeight = controller.getBoardHeight() + 100.0;
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);
        scene.getStylesheets().clear();
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("pacman.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        root.requestFocus();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My pacman.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Pixeboy';
    src: url("/src/res/fonts/Pixeboy.ttf");
}

.root{
    -fx-font-size: 16;
    -fx-font-family: "Pixeboy";
}
```

Comment: The path to the font file is fairly obviously wrong. (`src` is the source folder; it's typically not available at runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@font-face` can work BUT:

1. It needs to be first in your CSS file.
2. It **cannot use a leading slash in the src URL**.
3. The src URL must locate either

   - a web font via a valid full URL, e.g. `http:`, `https:` or `file:` protocols OR
   - to get it as a resource, it must be a *relative* path to the CSS file containing the @font-face directive.

If that is all set up correctly, then the instructions in the following answer work fine (verified with JavaFX 17):

- [JavaFX custom Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33342752/1155209)

An example URL that would work for the resources defined in the question is a src URL relative to the CSS file:

```
src: url("fonts/Pixeboy.ttf");
```

assuming that the font is actually located at that relative position to the CSS file referencing the `@font-face`.

When I tested, I used the [CSS and fonts](https://github.com/TheItachiUchiha/FontLoad/tree/master/src/main/resources) linked from the answer above.

**Troubleshooting**

1. If you use a leading slash in the src URL for @font-face (for example `src: url("/fonts/Pixeboy.ttf");`), you will get the following message and the font will not be loaded:

   ```
   Jan 12, 2022 2:31:09 PM javafx.css.CssParser reportException
   WARNING: Please report java.lang.NullPointerException at:
   ```

   The error message will be generated and the font will not load even if the path is correct to locate the font file from the root of the class/module path.
2. If you specify a location for the font which does not exist (for example `src: url("wrongfoldername/Pixeboy.ttf");`, you will get the following error message and the font will not load:

   ```
   Jan 12, 2022 2:43:18 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
   INFO: Could not load @font-face font [file:/<build-output-dir>/wrongfoldername/Pixeboy.ttf]
   ```

Comment: My font path is `src/res/fonts/Pixeboy.tff` and my css path now is `src/finalPacman/pacman.css` so in order to make it work i had to do: `url("../res/fonts/Pixeboy.tff")`.
Thank you for the detailed answer and the great explanation